# Relative links and includes (Org)

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, path

My problem is almost a repost from reddit ([original post](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/eg9pi1/relative_links_and_includes_org/)).
Recently, I opened a issue trying to explain what is going on ([issue](https://github.com/dangom/org-thesis/issues/10)), but the reddit post was clearer than my explanation and very similar to my problem.

> Say I have the files `main.org` and `other.org`, which are in different directories. In `main.org` I include `other.org`, and `other.org` has a hyperlink to an image `[[file:image.png]]`.
>
> `image.png` is in the same directory as `other.org` so when I export `other.org` to pdf, the image is found and included in the output.
>
> However, when exporting `main.org`, in the generated `main.tex` file it'll try to find `./image.png` even though that's in a different directory, so when exporting `main.org` none of the images with relative links are included in the output
>
> Anyone have advice on how I should fix this, without specifying the full path each time I link to an image?

The problem that I am facing is quite similar. The only difference is that I have a slightly different file structure, such as:

```
├── thesis.org
├── research_paper
│   └── other.org
|─────  figs
│       └── image.png
```

As from the original reddit post, the figure/file paths are not updated when exporting to PDF, causing a file with missing figures.

**Update:** An important difference between mine problem and that from reddit is that my `other.org` also have `#+INCLUDE`s insed and I guess that could be the source of the problem.
Is it possible to org updates the file paths in a recursive use of `#+INCLUDE`s?

**Expected behaviour:** Org-mode updates relative paths when using `#+include` command, and successfully generates a PDF file.

**Actual behaviour:** Org-mode use paths as it is when exporting to `.tex`.

**Emacs configuration:** Doom emacs based

**Org-mode version:** 9.6

Comment: I cannot reproduce it (Org mode version 9.6 (release_9.6-126-gf731d4)) with either the structure described in the `reddit` quote or with your structure. In both cases, I get a PDF displaying the images. In the second case, `other.org` uses `[[file:../figs/image.png]]` for the link and `thesis.org` `#+INCLUDE`s `./research_paper/other.org`. I also added a link to a second image in `thesis.org` like this: `[[file:./figs/fig2.png]]` and both images are shown in the exported PDF.